# AngularJS nested directive doesn't load when interpolated via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Something's telling me I have enough clues that I should be able to get this, but I've been down so many paths that my head is spinning to much to piece together a working solution.

I have a directive that introduces an ngRepeat nested inside another. The inner repeat attaches a class directive, `{{portlet.id}}`, according to objects in the collection over which it iterates. A sample id is `portlet-one`:

```
return ['canvas', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { windows : "=" },
        template:   '<div class="column" ng-repeat="column in windows.columns">' + 
                        '<div class="portlet {{portlet.id}}" ng-repeat="portlet in column.portlets"></div>' +
                    '</div>'
    };
}];
```

This produces valid html, but the `{{portlet.id}}` directive assigned by the inner repeat isn't being pulled in by Angular at runtime. I can't pull the inner repeat out of the template into `$compile` in the link function because I wouldn't have access to the the outer `$index`, so I tried `$apply` on scope in the link function (errors about digest as expected).

I've also verified `{{portlet.id}}` is valued.

What led me to `$compile` and `$apply` is that the directives load when I hard-code them:

```
template: '<div class="column" ng-repeat="column in windows.columns">' + 
             '<div class="portlet portlet-one" ng-repeat="portlet in column.portlets></div>' +
          '</div>'
```

I'm thinking Angular isn't being notified of the new inner directive. If that's the case, I'm not sure how to get Angular to parse back over the DOM changes to apply the new inner directives' template. Perhaps this has something to do with interpolation of the class directive?

**RESOLVED**

My observation of the working hard-coded inner-directive references was the key. Instead of trying to interpolate the `{{portal.id}}`, I introduce another directive to isolate the inner repeat collection:

```
template: '<div class="column" ng-repeat="column in windows.columns">' + 
              '<portlet-canvas portlets="column.portlets"></portlet-canvas>' +
          '</div>'
```

Then I build the html string manually and replace the `<portlet-canvas>` with the compiled result:

```
return ['portletCanvas', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { portlets : '=' },
        link : function (s, e, a) {

            var html = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < s.portlets.length; i++) {
                html += '<div ' + s.portlets[i].id + ' class="portlet"></div>';
            };

            var portletElement = $compile(html)(s);
            e.replaceWith(portletElement);
        }
    };
}];
```

Although this is working, I'm all ears if anyone has any better solutions for this functionality.

Comment: This is a bad design idea, IMO. Even if you manage to make it work, testing it will be incredibly difficult.

Comment: @rdodev - Interesting thought...perhaps you know a better way of loading directives based on user-defined collections?

Comment: I really don't know enough about your app's architecture to be able to give meaningful input. But defining child directives from rendering of the parent directive seems a bit obtuse. Again, IMO.

Comment: @rdodev - Thanks, anyway, for commenting...

Comment: I wouldn't refer to a directive from within the class attribute. I agree with rdodev, there seems to be something wrong with the design of this app. If you post more code you might get some better advice.

Comment: @StuR - The application is multi-windowed, each window having a configurable amount of columns, each column holding a configurable amount of portlets. All this is a per-user configuration object loaded from an ajax response. The portlets themselves are lazy-loaded depending on the that configuration object.

Comment: @StuR - Also updated the solution I came up with as I changed the directives back to attribute-based per best practices.